# The RAR archive format and authenticity verification

Tags: compression

The [changelog](http://www.rarlab.com/rarnew.htm) for RAR 5 mentions the following:

Features removed:

- authenticity verification feature did not provide the required level of reliability and was removed;
- ...

I didn't find any information as for what was wrong with the feature. Also, why not improve it instead of removing it?

Comment: We will not be able to comment on the internal decisions of a development team. They have methods to contact them: http://www.rarlab.com/feedback.htm

Comment: @schroeder If you won't, then maybe somebody else will. And why did you edit my question? What does WinRAR 5.4 (5.40?) has to do with the format version? WinRAR is merely a GUI program, one of several, to work with the RAR archive.

Comment: Actually, I'm about to close this question as being off-topic. I tried to edit it to reflect the link you provided, but I erred.